# Find matches of a variable in custom usermeta

Tags: user-meta

I have variable `$var` which is dynamic.
I want to find if there are any matches of this variable in custom user meta - `"authmeta"` and return the `user_id` of the corresponding entry if any matches are found.

Comment: Where and when do want to find this?

Comment: `$var` is a custom query variable and i want to find if it matches to any user meta of a user and if so i want to get the user id.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WP user query.

Assuming that your meta_key is `authmeta` you can use the following code to find the users with meta key `authmeta` and value of your `$var` variable.

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'authmeta', 'meta_value' => $var ) );
```